# how to show picture in the html by django

Tags: django

I can not show the picture in the html by django.
There is my project
[image]

This my project setting

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static/')
```

urls

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
urlpatterns=[
    path('',views.main_view,name='main_view'),
]
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

main.html

```
<img src="{% static '/my/1.jpg' %}" alt="My image">
```

There is my result.As you can see,the picture is desapper

setting.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/pic/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'pic/')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns+=static('/pic/', document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

main.html

```
<img src="pic/1.jpg" alt="My image">
```

[image]

Comment: what error do you get in your browser console? Have you set the `static` path in `settings.py`?

Comment: The error is 404. In setting.py I set the static by following:
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static/')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just should to remove slash, because, in the settings `STATIC_URL` already has it.

```
<img src="{% static 'my/1.jpg' %}" alt="My image">
               <!-- ^^^ -->
```

and by [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django.contrib.staticfiles.urls.staticfiles_urlpatterns) check `DEBUG` settings

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

> This helper function will only work if DEBUG is True

and try to use standard static instead of `staticfiles_urlpatterns`

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: I remove the slash like you. But I still cant see the picture

Comment: please check your `DEBUG` settings

Comment: # SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True
Is this debug setting.

Comment: i edit the answer with more information try it please

Comment: It doesn't work. But it worked when I change the name to pic. I show in the question

Comment: I forgot writer the app of main_html to INSTALLED_APPS.Thank you very much

Comment: Don't mention it)